# How to write structured logs so that message field is used by GCP Log Viewer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, structured-logging

### Question

Is there a way to write structured logs from Cloud Functions such that the message field is automatically displayed as the primary message in GCP Log Viewer?

Using [this test](https://github.com/drichardson/examples/tree/master/GoogleCloudPlatform/CloudFunctions/go), I've found that a field named *message* is sometimes used. For example, given these logs:

```
{"severity":"trace","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660044125-07:00","message":"Trace Basic"}
{"severity":"debug","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660047625-07:00","message":"Debug Basic"}
{"severity":"info","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660049425-07:00","message":"Info Basic"}
{"severity":"warn","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660051425-07:00","message":"Warn Basic"}
{"severity":"error","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660053225-07:00","message":"Error Basic"}
{"severity":"info","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660055125-07:00","message":"One line message"}
{"severity":"info","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660057025-07:00","message":"Line 1 of 2\nLine 2 of 2 for zlog.Info"}
{"severity":"info","myIntField":532,"myStringField":"howdy","myMultilineStringField":"Line 1 of 2\nLine 2 of 2 for zlog.Info with fields","time":"2020-03-09T12:21:13.660059925-07:00","message":"With Fields Example"}
```

The GCP Log Viewer will display something like this:

[image: Google Logging Console]

Notice the final entry, which should have a message *With Fields Example* instead has a top level message *{ "fields": { ... } }*.

### Extra Detail

Cloud Run has a [document describing special structured logging fields](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#special-fields) (i.e. severity and message) that Stackdriver logging will automatically pick up and use to populate the DEBUG/WARN/INFO/ERROR icon and top level message for the log entry in Stackdriver console.

> ### Special JSON fields in messages
>
> When you provide a structured log as a JSON dictionary, some special
>   fields are stripped from the jsonPayload and are written to the
>   corresponding field in the generated LogEntry as described in the
>   documentation for special fields.
>
> For example, if your JSON includes a severity property, it is removed
>   from the jsonPayload and appears instead as the log entry's severity.
>   The message property is used as the main display text of the log entry
>   if present. For more on special properties read the Logging Resource
>   section below.

The [corresponding document for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) has no information about special fields.

Comment: I am not much into Go but this test behavior with special fields seems inconsistent. Try reporting it [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151316427

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Google Cloud Platform logging that was fixed.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151316427